# Copying a large number of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, php

The aim is to duplicate and append each `.grid__item` into the `.gallery` element. The following code was my first instinct, and works fine, but can't help wonder if there is a more efficient way to write this. My concern is when the element count gets up to a high amount, that there will be some delay.

**Generate Dummy Elements (PHP)**

```
<section class="grid">
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) :
        $randH = rand(500, 1010);
        $randW = rand(500, 1010);
        $imgUrl = 'http://placehold.it/' . $randH . 'x' . $randW;
    ?>
        <article class="grid__item">
            <img src="<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>">
            <p><?php echo $imgUrl; ?></p>
        </article>
    <?php endfor;?>
</section>

<section class="gallery">
</section>
```

**Copy Elements (JS)**

```
let $gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid__item'),
    $gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');

let timeBefore = new Date().getTime();

for (let i = 0; i < $gridItems.length; i++) {
    $gallery.innerHTML += '<article class="gallery__item">' + $gridItems[i].innerHTML + '</article>';
}

let timeAfter = new Date().getTime();

console.log(timeAfter - timeBefore)
```

Comment: By "efficient", do you mean less code or faster execution?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific – looking for faster execution @jfriend00

Answer (score 2):

As a followup to your "selfie" answer :D

```
new Date().getTime()

// to

Date.now()
```

The effect is the same, but the difference is that you avoid generating a new `Date` object for the operation. `Date.now()` just returns the current timestamp.

```
$galleryItem.innerHTML = $gridItems[i].innerHTML
```

One problem with `innerHTML` is that it carries the state of whatever it was you fetched it from. This means if something happens to add the attribute `data-foo="bar"` into the element or its descendants, this gets copied over. You don't know what `data-foo="bar"` entails, and there might be side-effects.

An actual case is jQuery using an internal cache mapping of element references. It uses key of that mapping as a custom attribute on the element referenced. Using `innerHTML` would carry over this attribute to the new stuff, when it should not.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around with different solutions, I've come up with one that can handle a large number of DOM elements.

For 500 DOM elements (Image & Text), it completed the task in **113ms**, as compared to the above solution, which completed the task in **~17000ms**

```
let $gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid__item'),
    $gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery'),
    $galleryContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();

let timeBefore = new Date().getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < $gridItems.length; i++) {
    let $galleryItem = document.createElement('article');
    $galleryItem.className = 'gallery__item';
    $galleryItem.innerHTML = $gridItems[i].innerHTML
    $galleryContainer.appendChild($galleryItem)
}

$gallery.appendChild($galleryContainer);

let timeAfter = new Date().getTime();

console.log(timeAfter - timeBefore)
```

Comment: I highly discourage the use of `$` as some special indicator in variable names. Variables are variables, regardless of what they contain. If you want to convey what they really mean verbosely, name it appropriately.